# How to configure multiple instances of redis on macos with homebrew controlled with brew services start|stop

Tags: macos, redis, homebrew

I'm trying to run 2 or more instances of redis on different ports in macOS using homebrew. I can get part of the way there using launchCtl plist configuration, but what I really want to do is to be able to control both instances using:

```
brew services start|stop
```

Homebrew doesn't seem to recognize the second instance as an independent service. So this:

```
brew services start redis6381
```

fails as unrecognized service.

How do I get homebrew to recognize/register the second instance as a separate service.

I've tried creating a second homebrew.redis.service file, calling it homebrew.redis6381.service, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not possible without modifying the redis formula:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services/issues/198